# 'int' object is not callable in tkcalendar

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

I am trying to create a calendar function that will change the background of a cell to a different colour to show that there is an event on that day. I am using tkinter and tkcalendar.

**code**

```
    testPage=Toplevel()
    testPage.title("New Booking")
    testPage.geometry("1366x768")
    canvas=Canvas(testPage, width=1366, height=768)
    canvas.pack()
    frame=Frame(testPage)
    topbar=canvas.create_rectangle(0,0, 1366,30, fill="gray")
        

    lblDate=canvas.create_text(400,300, text="")
    date=canvas.create_text(50, 100, text="Date: ", font=("Helvetica", 14))
    date_today=datetime.now()
    cal=Calendar(testPage, width=12, background='saddle brown', foreground='white', mindate=date_today, disabledforeground='red')
    cal.place(x=150, y=100)
    day=date(2024, 3, 15)
    cal.calevent_create(day, "", tags="test")
    cal.tag_config("test", background="red")
```

The error that I am receiving is with the line `day=date(2024, 3, 15)` and the error it is giving me is `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`. I have tried using quotation marks around the dates `("2024", "3", "15")` and I have also tried putting hyphens between the dates `(2024-3-15)`

Is there something else I am missing that I can try? Really appreciate any advice you can give. Thank you!

Comment: You have overwritten `date` by the line `date=canvas.create_text(...)`.  So `date` is an integer and raise the exception when the line `day=date(...)` is executed.  Use other variable for the former line.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

The line `day=date(2024, 3, 15)` needed to be `day=datetime(2024, 3, 15)`.

Thank you!